# rewrite subdomain to domain

Tags: isapi-rewrite

I have a request that would look something like this `http://cariers.example.com/style/all.css` that would need to be rewritten to `http://www.example.com/style/all.css`. The request could be anything from a file like .css or .js to an actual page .aspx.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does the sub-domain points to the same location as the wWW domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try (for ISAPI_Rewrite 3):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(?:css|js|aspx))$ http://www.example.com/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks TonyCool, it could be from any subdomain though. Is there a more generic rule? Maybe `^*\.example\.com$`

Comment: Please try it the way I fixed my response